# How to Get pixel Intensity Values Matrix

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing, hexdump

I want to get the closer look of images pixels and also the pixel value matrix (which usually ranges 255 integer values I think). 
Do I need Matlab, or any other program/framework? (I am a Computer Science Student)

Attached a screenshot of what exactly I want (copied from http://www.whydomath.org/node/wavlets/imagebasics.html):

[image: snapshot]

Want you help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read an image ([like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JgJA.png)) from disk and display it on the screen in Matlab as follows:

```
>> img = imread('lion.png');
>> imshow(img)
```

[image: lion]

To get a closeup you just need to define the specific region you are interested in like so:

```
>> upper = 60;
>> lower = 100;
>> left = 40;
>> right = 80;
>> imshow(img(upper:lower, left:right))
```

[image: face]

Finally, you can also display the intensity values of a particular region of the image by simply typing:

```
>> row_min = 75;
>> row_max = 80;
>> col_min = 55;
>> col_max = 60;
>> img(row_min:row_max, col_min:col_max)

ans =

  159  199  180  184  181  168
  154  157  163  175  172  155
  158  135  143  156  167  149
  124  132  124  147  178  158
  126  138  123  145  178  159
  131  140  137  141  155  146
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the exact solution, this is what i was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

THe image will not necessarily have values of 255, it depends on the coding, for example if it is 16 bit grayscale image it can have values of up to ~65000, in other words it is 2^number_bits.

Assuming you already uploaded the image to Matlab into a matrix `I`, then simply by typing `I` in the command line and hitting `return` you will get the pixel values.

alternatively plotting the image using `imagesc(I)` you will have axis to the values of the individual pixels by choosing data cursor from the figure toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for providing me the easy solution, typing I and simple enter, it works :)